# Why does Jetbrains install its own JDK for use with its IDEs?

Tags: intellij-idea, rubymine, jetbrains-ide

I was looking checking the version of my Rubymine recently and noticed that it seems to be using a JVM provided by Jetbrains. What is the purpose of this? Why not use a JDK installed by the user?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of reasons.

- It allows them to have the IDEs run in a known, tested environment.
- It reduces the number of environments (versions) they have to verify.
- It keeps problems in a user's JVM from causing problems in their IDEs.

Comment: This is a fairly recent change from JetBrains. They used to not be included. It's much nicer this way, and modern hard drives have plenty of space.